# How can I add specific column of a Table to a DataSet?

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a a table `TBL_Person` with five columns :

```
Person_ID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Location
```

and I have a method which returns a dataset:

```
public  DataSet GetPerson()
{
    SqlCommand _select = new SqlCommand();
    _select.CommandText = "SP-GetAllPerson";
    _select.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _select.Connection = Connection.GetConnection;

    SqlDataAdapter _daPerson = new SqlDataAdapter(_select);

    DataSet _personDs = new DataSet();
    _daCountry.Fill(_personDs, "[TBL_Person]");

    return _personDs;
}
```

This method will return a dataset with columns:

```
Person_ID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Location
```

but I want my method return a dataset with these columns:

```
FirstName, LastName, Age
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Show your sp code also..

Comment: What means _"How can i add specific column of a Table to a DataSet"_? Change your stored-procedure accordingly. If you want to change it in C# the question would be _"How can i **remove** specific column from a Table of a DataSet"_?

Comment: select those column which you want to show in dataset.

Comment: oh,,It's depends on my sp, if i select FirstName , LastName, Age; it works?

Comment: @user3304614: yes :-)

Comment: Bear in mind too that a DataSet itself will not have any columns, rather the DataTable/s inside it

Answer (score 1):

Change your stored-procedure accordingly if you don't want to select all columns.

If you want to change it in C# you can remove unwanted columns via `table.Columns.Remove(name)`:

```
public DataSet GetPerson(IEnumerable<string> wantedColumns)
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection-String"))
    using (SqlDataAdapter _daPerson = new SqlDataAdapter("SP-GetAllPerson", connection))
    {
        _daPerson.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet _personDs = new DataSet();
        _daPerson.Fill(_personDs, "TBL_Person");
        DataTable tblPersonIds = _personDs.Tables["TBL_Person"];
        var allColumns = tblPersonIds.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName);
        // remove unwanted columns:
        foreach (string columnToRemove in allColumns.Except(wantedColumns))
            tblPersonIds.Columns.Remove(columnToRemove);
        return _personDs;
    }
}
```

You call this method in this way:

```
DataSet dsPerson = GetPerson(new[]{"FirstName", "LastName", "Age"});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don`t want to change your SP in data base then change your GetPerson() method in your .cs file like that:

```
public DataSet GetPerson()
{
    SqlCommand _select = new SqlCommand();
    _select.CommandText = "SP-GetAllPerson";
    _select.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _select.Connection = Connection.GetConnection; 
    SqlDataAdapter _daPerson = new SqlDataAdapter(_select);
    DataSet _personDs = new DataSet();
    _daPerson.Fill(_personDs, "[TBL_Person]");
    _personDs.Tables["TBL_Person"].Columns.Remove("Person_ID");
    _personDs.Tables["TBL_Person"].Columns.Remove("Location");
    return _personDs;

}
```

Otherwise you can change your stored procedure accordingly.